# Tiles are missing when request from Openlayer2

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql, apache

I have configured a Tile server and i followed the [Link](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) for OSM Tile server from switch2osm

everything is fine, except when i tried to get the tiles using Openlayers its not serving.

But if i give the same url like

```
http://192.168.1.127/osm_tiles/3/0/4.png
```

i can see the tiles

but map which is loaded from the Openlayes is not showing the tiles

when i check from the developer console of the chrome the response is HTTP code 200.

Anything i need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is CORS which is not allowing the tiles to load from 192.168.1.127

I configured the proxy and now its working fine.